# Issues in the java regex function.It is not validating. Help me

Tags: java

```
// I'm trying to validate my password but returns false and i am not able to find my error in it.
// i have tried alot but not finding whats wrong in it.        
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter your password");
            String mpassword = sc.next();
            boolean flag = Utilities.validatePassword(mpassword); //calling method 
            //from here
            if (!flag) {
                System.out.println("NOT VALID");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("PERFECT");
                break;
            }
            pro.setPassword(mpassword);
        }
    }
    //here is my regex validation 
    public class utilities {
        public static boolean validatePassword(String password) {
            String pattern = "((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%!]).{8,})";

            if (pattern.matches(password)) {
                System.out.println("matched");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (!passwordVariable.matches("((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%!]).{8,})")) { System.out.println("Password is not Strong enough!"); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String pattern = "((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%!]).{8,})";
if (pattern.matches(password)) { ... }
```

This is not how you match patterns. You need to use `Pattern` class.

```
String password = "harshal1A@";
String pattern = "((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%!]).{8,})";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(password);
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

Or, as pointed out by @Andreas, you just need to reverse the call.

```
password.matches(pattern)
```

---

In your regex, you are escaping `d` twice using `\\\\`. You only need to escape it once using `\\`.

Comment: You don't need `Pattern` and `Matcher`, you just need to reverse the call: `password.matches(pattern)`. --- Also, you silently fixed the ``\\\\d`` to ``\\d``. You should say something about that.

Comment: Done. @Andreas. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Punit, I’m getting true. Please try to run my code only in a separate file and once you replicate the results that I have, you may incorporate it in your code.

Comment: @Punit, can you accept the answer for future readers?

Comment: yes i can accept..and thank you to both of you

Comment: @Punit the accept button is the tick mark on the left of the answer. You’ll get 2 reputation points to accept the answer.